# Different HTML returned when using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to access a URL using python requests. But the results when using `requests.get` are different than what is shown in a browser. The browser shows a list of hotel rates, but the `requests.get` shows:

> 'No results found'.

```
import requests
url = 'https://m.ihg.com/hotels/ihg/us/en/searchresults?destination=Atlanta%2C+GA%2C+United+States&checkInDay=01&checkInMonthYear=12016&checkOutDay=02&checkOutMonthYear=12016&rateCode=IMGOV&numberOfRooms=1&numberOfAdults=1&numberOfChildren=0&lat=33.748901&lng=-84.3881&corporateNumber=&installationCode=&travelType=&officialType=&dvqBranch=&dvqRank=&installationName='
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5376e Safari/8536.25'}
response = requests.get(url)
response.text
```

Comment: Is there some JavaScript involved, perhaps?

Comment: I am getting list with your code.

Comment: I tried it again and believe I'm getting the list of hotels. Not sure what I did wrong the first time. I'll delete this post!

Comment: Would be better you use the real api of IHG. 
https://pcroomservice.ihg.com/io-docs

Comment: Wow I did not realize they had an API. Thanks for letting me know about that. I'll switch to that.